# Deploying to cloud run from bitbucket pipeline cause google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission denied on resource project None

Tags: google-cloud-run, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to deploy my django app on cloud run. I have followed the dedicated tutorial and it went fine.
Now I want to deploy it from my bitbucket pipeline.
Here are the line doing the job:

```
- export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/client-secret.json
- docker build . -t $IMAGE_NAME
- docker push $IMAGE_NAME
- gcloud run deploy devapi --image $IMAGE_NAME --platform managed --region europe-west1
```

Here is the complete stack trace of my error:

> File "/app/manage.py", line 17, in 
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 419, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 363, in execute
> settings.INSTALLED_APPS   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line
> 82, in **getattr**
> self._setup(name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line
> 69, in _setup
> self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line
> 170, in **init**
> mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in
> import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 991, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 843, in
> exec_module   File "", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "/app/main/settings.py", line 40, in 
> payload = client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/secretmanager_v1/services/secret_manager_service/client.py",
> line 1140, in access_secret_version
> response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py",
> line 145, in **call**
> return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py",
> line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
> return retry_target(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py",
> line 189, in retry_target
> return target()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py",
> line 69, in error_remapped_callable
> six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)   File "", line 3, in raise_from
> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission denied on
> resource project None."

So it feels like the problem comes from here:

> payload =
> client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

But when I log the name I do have the expected value.

Why doesit says that my project is None ? How can I set it ?

I tried to deploy adding the project to the commmand line like this:

```
gcloud run deploy devapi --image $IMAGE_NAME --platform managed --region europe-west1 --project myproject
```

same result...

I tried to replace my pipeline as follow:

```
- export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/client-secret.json
- gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml
- gcloud run deploy devapi --image $IMAGE_NAME --platform managed --region europe-west1 --project my-project
```

here is my cloud build:

```
steps:
  - id: "build image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}", "."]

  - id: "push image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}"]

  - id: "apply migrations"
    name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
    args:
      [
        "-i",
        "gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}",
        "-s",
        "${_PROJECT_ID}:${_REGION}:${_INSTANCE_NAME}",
        "-e",
        "SETTINGS_NAME=${_SECRET_SETTINGS_NAME}",
        "--",
        "python",
        "manage.py",
        "migrate",
      ]

  - id: "collect static"
    name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
    args:
      [
        "-i",
        "gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}",
        "-s",
        "${_PROJECT_ID}:${_REGION}:${_INSTANCE_NAME}",
        "-e",
        "SETTINGS_NAME=${_SECRET_SETTINGS_NAME}",
        "--",
        "python",
        "manage.py",
        "collectstatic",
        "--verbosity",
        "2",
        "--no-input",
      ]

substitutions:
  _INSTANCE_NAME: my-sql_instance
  _REGION: europe-west1
  _SERVICE_NAME: my_img_name
  _SECRET_SETTINGS_NAME:my_secret_name
  _PROJECT_ID: my_project
  _TAG: latest

images:
  - "gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}:${_TAG}"
```

And I still have the same result

Comment: Where is your stacktrace being generated from?  I get the impression that it is from the execution of your Cloud Run ... can you advise?

Comment: Indeed you are right, but as I change my pipeline using gcloud builds submit I receive the exact same stacktrace from cloud build on the apply migration step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was due to a misunderstanding of the bitbucket pipeline work. I thought that exporting my variable in it would make it available into my container but it does not.

I set my env var into my cloud run directly and this fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

One thing to confirm is whether you are using the correct values in the name variable. In two [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552808/) [issues](https://github.com/googleapis/python-secret-manager/issues/22), users received the same error by passing the project name instead of the project ID. You should make sure that the name variable is constructed in one of the [following ways](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#access) with correct values:

> `projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/{version_id}`
> `projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/latest`

Another thing to confirm is whether you have the [required permissions](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control) to access secrets in your service accounts. A relevant permission for this case would be `roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor` to access secret payload. This could also be a cause of this error. Finally, here is the access_secret_version [API documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/secretmanager/latest/secretmanager_v1/secret_manager_service.html?highlight=access_secret_version).